# How can I make the player land on the platform with sliding the part in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Am making a 2D Platformer game and while making the platforms for the player to land on it just slides though it and I've switching things up and can't find the solution

Changing the variables and all I got were the same results.

You can review the code so you see the errords because this has taken me hours.

Javascript:

```
> let isJumping = false;
> let isOnGround = true; // New flag to track whether the player is on the ground
> let positionY = 0;
> let positionX = 25; // Initial horizontal position
> let velocityY = 0;
> let velocityX = 0; // Horizontal velocity
> let gameActive = true;
> 
> const platforms = document.querySelectorAll('.platform');
> 
> function jump() {
> if (isOnGround && gameActive) { // Only allow jumping when on the ground
> isJumping = true;
> velocityY = 10; // Adjust the jump strength
> isOnGround = false;
>     }
> }
> 
> function moveLeft() {
> if (gameActive) {
> velocityX = -5; // Adjust the movement speed
>     }
> }
> 
> function moveRight() {
> if (gameActive) {
> velocityX = 5; // Adjust the movement speed
>     }
> }
> 
> function stopMovement() {
> velocityX = 0;
> }
> 
> function checkCollision() {
> const playerRect = player.getBoundingClientRect();
> 
> platforms.forEach((platform) => {
> const platformRect = platform.getBoundingClientRect();
> 
> if (
> playerRect.bottom > platformRect.top &&
> playerRect.top < platformRect.bottom &&
> playerRect.right > platformRect.left &&
> playerRect.left < platformRect.right
>         ) {
> Player is colliding with the platform
> isJumping = false;
> isOnGround = true;
> 
> Set the player's position to be directly on top of the platform
> player.style.bottom = platformRect.bottom + 'px';
> velocityY = 0;
>         }
>     });
> }
> 
> document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
> switch (event.code) {
> case 'Space':
> jump();
> break;
> case 'ArrowLeft':
> moveLeft();
> break;
> case 'ArrowRight':
> moveRight();
> break;
>     }
> });
> 
> document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
> if (event.code === 'ArrowLeft' || event.code === 'ArrowRight') {
> stopMovement();
>     }
> });
> 
> function gameLoop() {
> if (!gameActive) return;
> 
> velocityY -= 0.2; // Gravity effect, adjust as needed
> positionY += velocityY;
> 
> positionX += velocityX;
> 
> Adjust the minimum and maximum X position based on your game container width
> const minPositionX = 0;
> const maxPositionX = document.getElementById('game-container').offsetWidth - player.offsetWidth;
> 
> if (positionX < minPositionX) {
> positionX = minPositionX;
>     }
> 
> if (positionX > maxPositionX) {
> positionX = maxPositionX;
>     }
> 
> checkCollision();
> 
> if (positionY < 0) {
> positionY = 0;
> velocityY = 0;
> isJumping = false;
> isOnGround = true; // Set to true when the player is on the ground
>     }
> 
> player.style.bottom = positionY + 'px';
> player.style.left = positionX + 'px';
> 
> requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
> }
> 
> gameLoop();
>
```

Comment: I assume this isn't the actual code as there seems to be a comment without // before it? Having a look at your test - how can the player's bottom be above the platform's top AND the players top be below the platform's bottom at the same time?

Comment: @AHaworth Idk I just trying to find a solution to this problem; Am trying to make a solid platform for the player to land on without any problems